# Alamofire 'SecTrustCopyKey' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I recently added `pod 'Alamofire', '~> 5.4.0'`
to my project but in ***ServerTrustEvaluation.swift*** line 603 there is an error:

```
return SecTrustCopyKey(createdTrust) //'SecTrustCopyKey' is only available in iOS 14.0 or newer
```

how can I fix this? should is use earlier version?

Comment: That's weird. Just installed Alamofire 5.4.0 and in this line of this file has a call to a different function: `SecTrustCopyPublicKey(createdTrust)`.

Comment: Yes, that is not a line of code from Alamofire. Alamofire doesn't use `SecTrustCopyKey` at all.

Comment: You're right. I don't know why this happened. (It's files was locked and I'm sure it's not changed). I removed and then added it again and it changed!! thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could wrap that code in an `#available`-statement like so:

```
if #available(iOS 14, *) 
{
    return SecTrustCopyKey(createdTrust)
}
else 
{
    // Return something else here.
}
```

Obviously that means you won't be able to use `SecTrustCopyKey()` on devices running a lower iOS version.
Finding an equivalent for that function, which works for previous iOS versions, would be a solution. That can be used in the `else { ... }`.

Comment: thanks but I'm exactly looking for 'equivalent for that function'

Comment: [Here](https://alamofire.github.io/Alamofire/) is the complete documentation, where you should be able to find any functions available.

Answer (score 0):

you can change deployment target to 14 , if no requirement to support older version IOS

Comment: Instead of suggesting to change deployment target can you please share any other way